# "Find My" app (Mac): How can I prevent the zoom level from automatically resetting every few seconds?

Tags: find-my

On my Mac (running macOS 12.6 Monterey), in the "Find My" app, when I have the app set to view the current location of a single one of my contacts, after I zoom out (via clicking the "-" button in the app's UI), after about 4-10 seconds, the app's map reverts to it's default (fairly close range) zoom level.

How can I prevent the "Find My" app from periodically auto-resetting its zoom level in this manner, and instead "lock" the map view to my preferred zoom level?